# Software that monitor and summarize power consumption of the computer

Tags: windows, monitoring

I'm looking for software that monitor power consumption of the computer (desktop). I can't find with features like summarize power consumption in watt in an hour/day/week/month. By the way, I'm running Windows 8.1, every recommendation will be appreciated!

Comment: If you want the power consumption from the computer as a whole (and not its separet parts), I suggest you use one of these devices that you plug in between the power socket and the device you want to measure. That will give you the most reliable measurement over the measuring period you want.

Comment: The computer is not able to monitor is own power consumption! Not unless you connect it to various meters which has a computer interface.  In other words you need hardware, not software, to measure power consumption

Comment: I would recommend something like the kasa kp115, because the accuracy of any software version in questionable without testing.

Answer (score 0):

One may use [LocalCooling](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Local-Cooling.shtml) (gratis, non-portable)  ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/local-cooling)) to view the current power consumption:

[image]

Note that it doesn't see some Nvidia GPUs (e.g., it doesn't see my 3080 RTX attached to my MSI GS76 laptop running Win10).

Also, I don't know whether they log the consumption over the day/week/etc. and how accurate it is.

To view the Nvidia GPUs power consumption, one may use [HWInfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) (gratis, portable)  ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/local-cooling)):

[image]

HWInfo also gives the CPU power consumption:

[image]